# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException while getting VideoUri content from File

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to share a video(to social media) in an app I'm building. I'm using intents for which I need a Uri to parse. I'm trying to select items on a simple file manager (List activity) and then share them on long press. Thus I require the following code to get the Uri of the video for using it in the intents.

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
    String videoUriStr = null;
    long videoId = -1;

    Uri videosUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID };

    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection,
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " =?",
            new String[] { fileToShare }, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    if (videoId != -1)
        videoUriStr = videosUri.toString() + "/" + videoId;
    {

        return videoUriStr;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
The first few items on the ListActivity File manager file will share properly. But the latest videos show the error.

> Error: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: The paths has changed since 4.2 and its different to pre 4.2. Please use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() to get the base sd card path rather than hard-coding it

Comment: Its not being hardcoded. I used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my problem solved but I still don't understand why I faced that problem with the old code. Thanks for all the help.

```
public static Uri getVideoContentUriFromFilePath(Context context, File fileToShare) {
    String filePath = fileToShare.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID },
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[] { filePath }, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (fileToShare.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your cursor has 0 rows. So, the line `cursor.getLong(columnIndex);` throws `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`. please check for null and check whether any rows exist or not.

If there is no rows `cursor.moveToFirst()` will return  `false`.

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection,
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " =?",
            new String[] { fileToShare }, null);

if (cursor != null) {
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    if (videoId != -1)
    {
        videoUriStr = videosUri.toString() + "/" + videoId;
    }
  }
}
return videoUriStr;
```

The `MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA` field holds the path for the video file. So, if you are using uri (`content://mnt/sdcard/Videos/test.mp4`) to fetch the file change it to file path (`/mnt/sdcard/Videos/test.mp4`).

Comment: Thanks but, is the content resolver not accepting the data correctly?

Comment: what is the value stored in `fileToShare` variable?

Comment: Its the path to the video file

Comment: could you please tell the exact value stored in `fileToShare`?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/test.3gp

Comment: The videosUri is content://media/external/video/media . So Should I change it??

Comment: please revert to EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and Have you added the read permission in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`?

Comment: Permissions are all set. Reading and Writing. I believe its something to do with the context or content resolver. But I can't make out what is wrong with it. Seems alright isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop to check is cursor have data or not :

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
```

Replace with this code :

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: I agree the cursor is null. But I am certain that data is actually there on the filesystem. I believe, It isn't being fed into the content resolver properly.So could it be something wrong with the contentResolver declaration?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

means your cursor has no data.

use check for cursor emptyness:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
}
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario does not depend on phone to phone. The problem is that your cursor has no data.

You can use cursor.moveToFirst() which returns false if the cursor is empty, or use cursor.getCount() to know the number of rows in the cursor.

e.g

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
}
cursor.close();
```

or

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Try to pass null selection to see whether the contentResolver can find any data. That could give some insight. contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection,
            null,null, null);

Comment: Yes, The sharing chooser pops up. So it's definitely something to do with the file location right?

Comment: Yes, and it seems your value in fileToShare doesn't match the MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA.

Comment: How do you determine value to store in fileToShare?

Comment: I am thinking it will work when you set the correct fileToShare??

Comment: I used a ListActivity for a simple File manager. And the item picked on it returns the item path. This value is the fileToShare ie, /storage/emulated/0/testdir/test.3gp

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to check the size of the cursor.

```
if(cursor.size()>0)
```

{
// do here

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
if (videoId != -1)
    videoUriStr = videosUri.toString() + "/" + videoId;
{

    return videoUriStr;
}
 }
```